# Display Timer in TextView

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.android

I trying to display a timer in a TextView. I start like this :

```
    Imagine = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Imagine);
    Timer = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Timer);

    Imagine.Click += delegate {
        var TimerClick = new Timer();
        TimerClick.Interval=10000;
        TimerClick.Enabled=true;
        Timer.Text= TimerClick.ToString();
    }
```

But in the TextView get "System.Timers.Timer".

Any advice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (probably just need `()` on the end of `ToString`). Can you explain further what you're trying to do?

Comment: What do you _wish_ `TimerClick.ToString` would do?

Comment: @HABO Convert the Timer to string to be able to display in TextView

Comment: And the missing of () is just a copy mistake.

Comment: @Dragos That's exactly what you've already said, that doesn't tell us anything or answer our questions. There's no string representation of a timer object. Again, be more specific about what *exactly* you are trying to do.

Comment: @tnw Ok then can you tell me how to display the timer in a TextView?

Comment: @Dragos No, I can't until you give me some more details. For the third time, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Tell us exactly what you wanted to see in your TextView

Comment: Do you want it to announce "Now!"? Or "At the time the tone will be 1300Hz."? Or just "Tick."?

Comment: @tnw I just wanna display in a TextView a 10 seconds count down timer when a Button is clicked.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! So the question is how to display a countdown from 10 to 0 that updates once per second. You'll need a timer that ticks each second and, if you don't mind some slop, decrements a counter and displays the resulting value. If the value is zero then stop the timer. (The slop comes about since the timer may not fire at exactly one second intervals, hence the overall time may stretch out somewhat. You can check the system time on each tick and correct as needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo you can run:

```
static int count;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

   timer.Interval = 1000;
   timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine(count--);
      if (count < 0) timer.Stop();
   };

   //simulate button press
   while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
   {
      count = 10;
      timer.Start();
   }
}
```

When the button is clicked (i.e. a key is pressed here), reset the `count` and start the timer.  When the `count` hits zero, stop the timer.  If the button is pressed in the middle of a countdown, restart it.

Comment: Can you enlighten me with something? Why then when I replace Console.WriteLine(count--); with TextView.Text = (count--).ToString(); doesn't work? I mean the TextView text doesn't change.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: Never mind :) I solved the problem.